# UNIXのパイプ処理のようにストリームを扱いたい

Tags: common-lisp

AとBという2つのストリームがあった場合、Aのストリームを読み込み、処理を加え、Bのストリームに結果を受け流すような処理はどのように書くのでしょうか。

一旦Aのストリームの内容を書き出して処理を加え、その結果でBのストリームを作る、というような方法しかないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 一旦Aのストリームの内容を書き出して処理を加え、その結果でBのストリームを作る、というような方法しかないのでしょうか。

理想的には

```
(defun f (in out) (loop (write-char (read-char in) out)))
(defun g (in out) (loop (write-char (read-char in) out)))
(let ((in ...) (out ...) (pipe ...))
  (make-thread (lambda () (f in pipe))
  (make-thread (lambda () (g pipe out)))
```

と書きたいのですよね。しかし、`(pipe ...)` に相当するものが無いので、CLの範疇では

```
(defun read-all (in) ...)
(defun f (in) (make-next-input-stream (dosomething (read-all in)))))
(defun g (in) (make-next-input-stream (dosomething (read-all in)))))
(let ((in ...))
  (read-all (g (f in))))
```

とするしか無く、本当のパイプとは似ていない形になってしまいます。いくつか方法が考えられます。

1. clで`(pipe ...)`を実装してしまうこと。しかし、streamクラスはbuilt-in-typeなので継承できません。NG.
   追記: gray-streamで拡張できるようです。
   http://kurohuku.blogspot.jp/2009/11/gray-stream.html
   ここの make-virtual-stream は実質pipeですね。
2. iolibを使う。`(iolib.syscalls:pipe)`はあるのですが、帰ってくるのがFile Descriptor番号なので、いかんせん使いにくい。ラッパがあればいいのですが、ないようです。そこで`mkfifo`を使いましょう。

たとえば以下のような感じ。

```
(unwind-protect
  (let ((fifo "/tmp/myfifo")
        (in ...) (out ...))
    (iolib.syscalls:MKFIFO fifo 255)
    (with-open-file (fifoin fifo :direction :input)
      (with-open-file (fifoout fifo :direction :output)
        (make-thread (lambda () (f in fifoout))
        (make-thread (lambda () (g fifoin out))))))
 (delete-file fifo))
```

たぶんうまく行くはず。

3. sbclなら `sb-unix:unix-pipe` が返してきたFD番号を `SB-SYS:make-fd-stream` でストリームに出来ます。これもユーティリティーがあればいいのに。あと、生成したpipeを消す方法がわからないのですが大丈夫なのか不明です。

例:

```
(multiple-value-bind (read-fd write-fd) (sb-unix:unix-pipe)
  (let ((pipeout (SB-SYS:make-fd-stream write-fd :output t))
        (pipein  (SB-SYS:make-fd-stream read-fd  :input  t)))
     ...))
```

iolibがもっとしっかり使いやすくなっていればいいのですけどね。
pipe系の問題としては、lispオブジェクトを渡せないということでしょうか。
charしか流せません。

4. cl-asyncとかどうなってるんでしょうね。なにか出来そうな気がしますが、知りません。